# Bash script: Installs Docker, Skaffold, Minikube, and kubectl on a Linux system

Tags: bash

sims installation process is ok, but when i'm starting minikube i'm getting error:

> Exiting due to DRV_NOT_HEALTHY: Found driver(s) but none were healthy. See above for suggestions how to fix installed drivers.

and then when i'm manually running command that i already have in script:

> sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker

minikube starts...

any suggestions? here is whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_command {
    local cmd="$1"
    local spinner_text="$2"

    echo -n "$spinner_text"
    {
        eval "$cmd" &>/dev/null
    } &
    local spinner=$!

    local spin='-\|/'
    local i=0
    while kill -0 $spinner 2>/dev/null
    do
        i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
        printf "\r$spinner_text ${spin:$i:1}"
        sleep .1
    done

    wait $spinner
    local exit_code=$?

    if [[ $exit_code != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error: $cmd failed with exit code $exit_code."
        exit $exit_code
    fi

    echo "Done."
}

# Update package lists
run_command "apt-get update" "Updating package lists... "

# Install Docker
run_command "apt-get install -y docker.io" "Installing Docker... "

# Install Skaffold
run_command "curl -Lo skaffold https://storage.googleapis.com/skaffold/releases/latest/skaffold-linux-amd64 && chmod +x skaffold && sudo mv skaffold /usr/local/bin" "Installing Skaffold... "

# Install Minikube
run_command "curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin" "Installing Minikube... "

# Install kubectl
run_command "curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/\`curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt\`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl && sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/" "Installing kubectl... "

# Add the current user to the Docker group
run_command "sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker" "Adding user to Docker group... "

# Add virtual host to /etc/hosts
run_command "echo '192.168.49.2    hcms.dev' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts" "Adding virtual host to /etc/hosts... "

echo "Installation complete."
```

Comment: Newgrp might need to execute in the same process.

Comment: @konsolebox what u mean by execute in the same process? this is not enought? 
 :run_command "sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker" "Adding user to Docker group... " if not, please can u show example, where how to put it?

oh and by the way, thank u for ur answer and time. <3

Comment: Try not running it with `run_command` temporarily and see if it helps. Just `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker`. And I mean in the script still.

Comment: why don't you use Ansible instead.